# RealmSwift update object in different threads(closures)

Tags: swift3, realm

Kindly help with Real objects adding/updating
I'd like store and update User class.
User class consist of Client class,
Client class consist of Avatar property and Rooms List.
Issue is that I'm facing error "The Realm is already in a write transaction" because my Client class avatar property and rooms list are fetched and pushed to Realm in different closures at the same time.

```
func fetchRooms() {
    roomsDelegate?.contactRooms(entityID: entityID,
                                success: {rooms in
                                    self.addRooms(rooms: rooms)
                                },
                                fail: { error in
                                    print (error)
                                })

}

func addRooms(rooms: [VMRoom]?) {
    if let r = rooms {
        do{
            try realm?.write {
                realm?.add(r, update: true)
                self.rooms.append(objectsIn: r)
            } }
        catch let e {
            print(e.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}


func getAvatarURL() {
    do{
        try realm?.write {
            avatarURL = avatarDelegate?.contactAvatarURL(eExtention: eExtention)                
        } }
    catch let e {
        print(e.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Realm is saying, you've got an error in your app's logic if you're trying to open up two write transactions in one thread. I'd recommend you review your logic to see if you can make it more streamlined.

But in any case, to fix your current code, one way to mitigate this would be to check you're not already in a write transaction when you're setting the avatar URL.

```
func getAvatarURL() {
    let inWriteTransaction = realm?.isInWriteTransaction
    do {
        if !inWriteTransaction {
            realm?.beginWrite()
        }

        avatarURL = avatarDelegate?.contactAvatarURL(eExtention: eExtention)

        if !inWriteTransaction {
            try realm.commitWrite()
        }
    catch let e {
        print(e.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```